# How to pivot with binning with complicated condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like below

```
age  type days 
1    a    1
2    b    3
2    b    4
3    a    5   
4    b    2
6    c    1
7    f    0
7    d    4
10   e    2
14   a    1
```

first I would like to binning with age

age

`[0~4]`

```
age  type days  
1    a    1
2    b    3
2    b    4
3    a    5   
4    b    2
```

Then sum up and count days by grouping with `type`

```
   sum count
a   6   2
b   9   3
c   0   0
d   0   0
e   0   0
f   0   0
```

Then I would like to apply this method to another binns.

[5~9] 
[11~14]

My desired result is below

```
   [0~4]         [5~9]      [10~14]
   sum count  sum count  sum count
a   6   2      0   0      1   1
b   9   3      0   0      0   0
c   0   0      1   1      0   0
d   0   0      4   1      0   0
e   0   0      0   0      2   1
f   0   0      0   1      0   0
```

How can this be done?
It is very complicated for me..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a `pivot_table` with `pd.cut` if you do not care too much about column ordering as *count* and *sum* are not paired together under the bin. With manipulation you can change such ordering.

```
df['bin'] = pd.cut(df.age, [0,4,9,14])

pvtdf = df.pivot_table(index='type', columns=['bin'], values='days', 
                       aggfunc=('count', 'sum')).fillna(0)

#       count                   sum               
# bin  (0, 4] (4, 9] (9, 14] (0, 4] (4, 9] (9, 14]
# type                                            
# a       2.0    0.0     1.0    6.0    0.0     1.0
# b       3.0    0.0     0.0    9.0    0.0     0.0
# c       0.0    1.0     0.0    0.0    1.0     0.0
# d       0.0    1.0     0.0    0.0    4.0     0.0
# e       0.0    0.0     1.0    0.0    0.0     2.0
# f       0.0    1.0     0.0    0.0    0.0     0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

We'll use some stacking and groupby operations to get us to the desired output.

```
string_ = io.StringIO('''age  type days 
                         1    a    1
                         2    b    3
                         2    b    4
                         3    a    5   
                         4    b    2
                         6    c    1
                         7    f    0
                         7    d    4
                         10   e    2
                         14   a    1''')
df = pd.read_csv(string_, sep='\s+')

df['age_bins'] = pd.cut(df['age'], [0,4,9,14])

df_stacked = df.groupby(['age_bins', 'type']).agg({'days': np.sum,
                         'type': 'count'}).transpose().stack().fillna(0)
df_stacked.rename(index={'days': 'sum', 'type': 'count'}, inplace=True)

>>> df_stacked
age_bins    (0, 4]  (4, 9]  (9, 14]
      type                         
sum   a        6.0     0.0      1.0
      b        9.0     0.0      0.0
      c        0.0     1.0      0.0
      d        0.0     4.0      0.0
      e        0.0     0.0      2.0
      f        0.0     0.0      0.0
count a        2.0     0.0      1.0
      b        3.0     0.0      0.0
      c        0.0     1.0      0.0
      d        0.0     1.0      0.0
      e        0.0     0.0      1.0
      f        0.0     1.0      0.0
```

This doesn't produce the exact output you listed, but it's similar, and I think it will be easier to index and retrieve data from. Alternatively, you could do use the following to get something like the desired output.

```
>>> df_stacked.unstack(level=0)
age_bins (0, 4]      (4, 9]      (9, 14]     
          count  sum  count  sum   count  sum
type                                         
a           2.0  6.0    0.0  0.0     1.0  1.0
b           3.0  9.0    0.0  0.0     0.0  0.0
c           0.0  0.0    1.0  1.0     0.0  0.0
d           0.0  0.0    1.0  4.0     0.0  0.0
e           0.0  0.0    0.0  0.0     1.0  2.0
f           0.0  0.0    1.0  0.0     0.0  0.0
```