# How to pivot after function in MS access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Table1

```
contractdate  age   
2013/4/1      4     
2014/4/3      10
2015/5/4      11
2014/4/2      15
2015/8/7      17
```

First I would like to Get Current age by

`Datediff("yyyy",contractdate,"2017/1/1")+age AS currentage`

`YEAR(contractdate) AS contractyear`

```
contractdate  age  currentage  contractyear   
2013/4/1      4      7          2013
2014/4/3      10     12         2014
2015/5/4      11     12         2015
2014/4/2      15     17         2014
2015/8/7      17     18         2015
```

Second,I would like to pivot,by binning with `currentage`

```
        2013  2014  2015
[0,4]    0     0     0      
[5,9]    1     0     0
[10,14]  0     1     1
[15,19]  0     1     1
```

I know below format, but couldnt figure out how to transform data before pivoting.

`TRANSFORM
SELECT
GROUP BY
PIVOT`

How can this be done?
I am happy someone tell me.

Comment: Wow, I never thought a Python poster would ask an MS Access question a day later! And the [very one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41993561/how-to-pivot-with-binning-with-complicated-condition-in-pandas) I recently answered on similar topic. Do note you can also do this in pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your needs may be too nuanced for the *Crosstab Wizard* as you will need a derived table/subquery to conditionally calculate *age bins* and then aggregate for crosstab. Plus you need a calculated `ORDER BY` logic to get bins to line up properly since they would be considered string. Finally you will need conversion to return zeros instead of `NULL`.

```
TRANSFORM CInt(Nz(Count(*),0)) AS bincount
SELECT main.agebin
FROM 
   (SELECT c.contractdate, c.age, c.currentage, c.contractyear,
          IIF(c.currentage BETWEEN 0 AND 4, '[0-4]', 
              IIF(c.currentage BETWEEN 5 AND 9, '[5-9]',
                  IIF(c.currentage BETWEEN 10 AND 14, '[10-14]',
                      IIF(c.currentage BETWEEN 15 AND 19, '[15-19]', NULL)))) AS agebin
FROM ContractAgeTable c) AS main

GROUP BY main.agebin
ORDER BY CInt(Replace(Mid(main.agebin, 2, 2), '-', ''))
PIVOT main.contractyear IN (2013, 2014, 2015)

-- agebin   2013    2014    2015
-- [5-9]    1       0       0
-- [10-14]  0       1       1
-- [15-19]  0       1       1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the *Crosstab Wizard* in Access - it does all the basic plumbing. Then study the SQL is creates and adjust as needed.