# Change pandas pivot table bins range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, data-analysis

I have a pandas pivot table and I want to change the bin ranges to calculate from 0.

> ```
> Hour_Num  (0, 12] (12, 15]    (15, 20]    (20, 24]
> today_qty yesterday_qty   today_qty   yesterday_qty   today_qty   yesterday_qty   today_qty   yesterday_qty
> channel_name                              
> Ajio  22  68  0   55  0   53  0   32
> Amazon    3   6   0   3   0   3   0   0
> D2C   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
> Flipkart  25  32  0   18  0   42  0   26
> Limeroad  1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
> Meesho    3   7   0   3   0   1   0   0
> Myntra    61  102 0   53  0   96  0   55
> Nykaa 12  8   0   10  0   14  0   18
> Snapdeal  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
> TataCliq  3   9   0   2   0   5   0   5
> ```

I want the bins as (0, 12] (0, 15] (0, 20] (0, 24]. I want to show total no of orders from beginning of the day till 12 PM, 3 PM, 8 PM and midnight 12.

12: 12 PM
15: 3 PM
20: 8 PM
24: Midnight 12

This is my code:

```
df['Hour_Num'] = pd.cut(df.order_hour,[0,12,15,20,24])

pivot_df = df.pivot_table(index='channel_name', values=(['yesterday_qty','today_qty']), columns=['Hour_Num'], aggfunc=('sum')).fillna(0)

pivot_df = pivot_df.swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

I appreciate any hint or solution. Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) with an expected output.

Comment: Also you can't do that using `.cut`, since it expects as bins either (i) the number of bins, (ii) a monotonically increasing sequence of scalars, or (iii) a non-overlapping `IntervalIndex`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pivot with binning with complicated condition in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41993561/how-to-pivot-with-binning-with-complicated-condition-in-pandas)